# How to implement ACL in CakePHP plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0, acl

I am developing a CakePHP 2's plugin but I dont know how define ACL for it.

Its the same way like doing for an application? Or it is solved of another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across your question today in my attempts to solve the same problem myself. My answer will make most sense, assuming you've followed the CakePHP tutorial "Simple ACL Controlled Application".

To answer your question directly, the answer is yes. Defining the ACO (Access Control Object) is the same as any application controller. With one slight modification. You first create an ACO record to represent the plugin itself, which uses the root ACO as it's parent_id. The plugin controllers will subsequently use the plugin ACO as their parent_id (and the plugin controller actions will use the plugin controller ACO as their parent_id).

Does this make sense?

For anyone who arrived here because they've successful established an ACL/Auth controlled application, have built a custom plugin (with the intention of accessing it via url), properly configured ACL and STILL cannot access their plugin. I'd like to offer the following advice, which cost me several days of relentless effort.

In my case, I had developed a plugin to function as a simple asset manager (add directories, upload/download files) called "Assets". I followed exact cake specification in setting up a plugin AppController and AppModel to allow access via url. After properly configuring ACL I still could not access the plugin controllers/action. In the end, what was causing the issue was a"requestAction" residing in elements I had designed to function has the top & side navigation. To alleviate the problem all that was required was to add "plugin" => null to the url array.

### before:

$this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'get_side_navigation'));

### after:

$this->requestAction(array('plugin' => null,'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'get_side_navigation'));